# Improve visualization of a large network plot in qgraph package

Tags: r, neural-network, correlation, r-qgraph

I came across with the qgraph package and I'm so grateful I did because I have got some many beautiful and informative plots. I am currently working with a larger database of 755 metabolites measured in 15 bacterial species at 2 time points and I a huge plot that I am unable to attach here because I do not have 10 reputation points.

I would like to see how the metabolites correlate among each other but I would like to see only the significant correlations. Therefore, I used the code that Sacha Epskam kindly provide in his website:

```
  oralnet<-read.csv2('net24h.csv',dec='.')##file with the 755 metabolites
  oralnet2<-oralnet[,2:756]##remove the first column with name of bacteria 
  namesnet<-read.csv2('netID.csv',dec='.') #file with the names of the bacteria
  nameschars <- as.character(t(namesnet)[2:nrow(t(namesnet)),])
  uniquechars <- unique(as.character(t(namesnet)[2:nrow(t(namesnet)),]))
  nameslist<-list("Carbon"  =which(nameschars==uniquechars[1]),
            "Nitrogen"=which(nameschars==uniquechars[2]),
            "PS"=which(nameschars==uniquechars[3]),
            "Nutrient"=which(nameschars==uniquechars[4]),
            "Peptide"=which(nameschars==uniquechars[5]))

  rownames(oralnet2)<-c("Aa","Fn","Pg","Pi","Tf","Smut","Ssob","An","Csput","Sgord",
  "Avisc","Ssal","Ssang","Vparv","Smitis")

  qgraph(cor(oralnet2, use="pairwise"),minimum=0.25,groups=nameslist,
  legend=TRUE,borders=FALSE,label.cex=0.4, labels=names(oralnet2),
  layout="spring",line = 2.5,legend.cex=0.5,label.scale=FALSE,
  graph="sig2",alpha=cc(0.0001,0.001))
```

As I mentioned, there are many correlations and I would like to remove some nodes. I know that qgraph does not allow you to remove nodes and therefore I was wondering if there is any way to improve the visualization of the plot. I will really appreciate any suggestion!! Once again, I thank you for your time and consideration!

Best wishes,

Emma

Comment: I can't run your example, but what if you removed the correlations yourself prior to passing the object (`cor(...)`) to qgraph?

Comment: Hello! I'm sorry for the silly question, but how do I do it?

Comment: `cor` returns a matrix. Search SO on how to subset a matrix given a threshold. This is pretty RTM, so you should have little problem finding the solution.